# How to access usb mass storage in android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing an android program. but have a problem. How to directly access USB mass storage in android ndk?

example:

```
int vnHandle = open("/dev/sdb1","rw");

read(vnHandle, buffer,size);
write(vnHandle, buffer,size);
```

and so on.

Is this impossible?
help me.

Comment: You can do this with root access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to limit yourself to already mounted locations, such as `/sdcard/`.

Otherwise, no problem to access mass storage.